# Qual anotação é usado no mapeamento ORMLite para o Enum como Foreign?

Tags: java, android, ormlite

Tenho a classe Cliente e o enum AnimaisEstimacao, onde um cliente pode ter 1 ou mais animais de estimação. Ficaria assim:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "cliente")
public class Cliente{

@DatabaseField(generateId = true)
private Long id;

@DatabaseField
private String nome;

@????
List<AnimaisEstimacao> animais;
```

Enum AnimaisEstimacao

```
public enum AnimaisEstimacao{
GATO(0);
CACHORRO(1);
PASSARO(2);
OUTROS(3);
//implementacao
}
```

Qual seria a anotação ORMLite para o Enum AnimaisEstimacao presente na classe Cliente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há um tempo atrás eu fiz um código parecido. Tenta resolver dessa forma:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "cliente")
public class Cliente{

@DatabaseField(generateId = true)
private Long id;

@DatabaseField
private String nome;

@ForeignCollectionField(foreign = true, eager = true)
Collection<AnimaisEstimacaoCliente> animais;
```

Então  você cria uma classe, por exemplo, "AnimaisEstimacaoCliente" com os campos "AnimalEstimacao" e "Cliente" para que haja o relacionamento. Esta classe deve ser uma representação de uma tabela no banco de dados.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "animais_estimacao_cliente")
    public class AnimaisEstimacaoCliente{

    @DatabaseField(generateId = true)
    private Long id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(foreign = true )
    private Cliente cliente;


    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.ENUM_INT)
    private AnimalEstimacao animal;
}
```

Mais informações estão disponíveis nos links:

- http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#index-collections-of-objects
- https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/tree/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/foreignCollection

Comment: Neste caso, tenho que mapear o Enum? Valew ae!

Comment: Desculpe, não fui claro no meu raciocínio inicial. Alterei o post inicial para melhor entendimento.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a documentação do ORMLite ficaria assim:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "cliente")
public class Cliente{

@DatabaseField(generateId = true)
private Long id;

@DatabaseField
private String nome;

@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.ENUM_INTEGER)
List<AnimaisEstimacao> animais;
```

Comment: Mas neste caso, tenho que mapear o enum AnimaisEstimacao? Isso é possível? Valew